# Encrypt file with AES-256 and Decrypt file to its original format

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, aes, filenames

I have to build a project for encryption and decryption of files in AES-256.
So, I have to encrypt files and those files could be of any format like text file, image file, video file or any kind of file with any format, 
And have to encrypt those files and store them on device with different format like ***.anuj** (extension name).

Suppose I encrypted file and made new file with custom extension. 
While decryption that file how am I supposed to know that original file was text file or image or of any other format.

My question is
1. Do i need to add extra character while saving encrypted file in custom format like for image (**abcd_img.anuj**), for text (**abcd_txt.anuj**).
At the time of decryption, I can get the original file format from that extra embedded character img for image, txt for text. So that i can decrypt to that file format.

But this is bulky process because there are number of formats. Even image has multiple formats (.gif, .png, .jpg etc).

What approach should I choose before working on this project?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on files, then the only information that you might need to re-create that file after decryption is the file name and file extension.

One way to do this is to simply encrypt the file as-is without a special file format as "name.ext.anuj" when the file that you encrypted was "name.ext". It contains everything to re-create the original file.

The problem with this is that the filename is shown. Sometimes meta-data such as a filename is all an attacker needs. Think about when your spouse finds a file "divorce.odf.anuj".

In those cases, you can define a new file format. You can for example take the filename, write it into a stream (maybe prepend it with the filename length which [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) provides) and write the actual file contents after that as `byte[]`. Now, you can encrypt the whole thing. When you decrypt it, simply read the filename from the front and write to this file the remaining decrypted bytes.

Comment: Adding custom file extension is necessity in this application. This is the requirement. My files could be any and if i send it to other device through mail. user can only open that file in my application. Because my application know that custom extension. There i have to find which file that was originally so that i can decrypt it to original one.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. You would use a custom extension to denote encrypted files.

Comment: Thanks for answering, one more question i want to ask that is how do Android OS supposed to know that encrypted file with custom extension has to open in specific application, Right now OS saying that "Unable to find application to perform this action". Do i need to provide any permission in menifest or what so that os will know that for this extension i have to open this particular application.

Comment: I have no idea how android handles custom file extensions.