# Why is python adding "" to my filenames when decrypting AES?

Tags: python, linux, encryption, cryptography, filenames

I'm not running into any error just the output for my program is doing something strange. I've also noticed this thread here: [Encrypt file with AES-256 and Decrypt file to its original format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070309/encrypt-file-with-aes-256-and-decrypt-file-to-its-original-format). This is my own approach to this issue, so I hope this isn't considered a duplicate. I'll post my code below, and explain how it functions. (Not including the encryption code)

## For Encryption

```
path = 'files/*'   
files = glob.glob(path)
with open('extensions.txt', 'w') as extension:
    for listing in files:
        endfile = os.path.splitext(listing)[1]
        extension.write(endfile + "\n")
extension.close()

for in_filename in files:
    out_filename1 = os.path.splitext(in_filename)[0]
    out_filename = out_filename1 + '.pycrypt'
    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as in_file, open(out_filename, 'wb') as out_file:
        encrypt(in_file, out_file, password)
    in_file.close()
    out_file.close()
    os.remove(in_filename)
print 'Files Encrypted'
```

## For Decryption

```
password = raw_input('Password-> ') 
path = 'files/*'   
files = glob.glob(path)
for in_filename in files:
    f=open('extensions.txt')
    lines=f.readlines()
    counter+=1
    out_filename1 = os.path.splitext(in_filename)[0]
    out_filename = out_filename1 + lines[counter]

    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as in_file, open(out_filename, 'wb') as out_file:
        decrypt(in_file, out_file, password)
    in_file.close()
    out_file.close()
    os.remove(in_filename)
print 'Files Decrypted'
```

The code takes all the files in a folder, and encrypts them using AES. Then changes all the files extensions to .pycrypt, saving the old extension(s) into a file called "extensions.txt". After decryption it gives the files there extensions back by reading the text file line by line.

Here's the issue, after decryption every file goes from this:

15.png, sam.csv

To this

```
15.png, sam.csv
```

I've also noticed that if I re-encrypted the files with the  symbol, the "extensions.txt" go from this:

```
15.png
sam.csv
bill.jpeg
```

To this (notice the spaces):

```
15.png

sam.csv

bill.jpeg
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: If I can believe the little box that firefox draws, it should be unicode F823, but that doesn't seem to be a valid unicode character. So something really is off.

Comment: I can't tell what character it is, when I click "Rename File" to copy the character it vanishes. I just got that one from the web.

Comment: You can check within python if you're interested: [`import unicodedata; unicodedata.name(weirdchar)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13106217/5067311).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> file.readline([size])
> ```
>
> Read one entire line from the file. ***A trailing newline character is kept in the string (but may be absent when a file ends with an
>   incomplete line).*** [6] If the size argument is present and
>   non-negative, it is a maximum byte count (including the trailing
>   newline) and an incomplete line may be returned. When size is not 0,
>   an empty string is returned only when EOF is encountered immediately.
>
> ```
> file.readlines([sizehint])
> ```
>
> Read until EOF using ***`readline()`*** and return a list containing the lines thus read. If the optional sizehint argument is present, instead
>   of reading up to EOF, whole lines totalling approximately sizehint
>   bytes (possibly after rounding up to an internal buffer size) are
>   read. Objects implementing a file-like interface may choose to ignore
>   sizehint if it cannot be implemented, or cannot be implemented efficiently.

This means that `lines[counter]` doesn't only contain the file extension, but also the newline character after that. You can remove all whitespace at the beginning and end with: `lines[counter].strip()`.

A better way to do this is to encrypt a file "a.jpg" as "a.jpg.enc", so you don't need to store the extension in a separate file.

Comment: Can you explain why it shows up as a weird invalid unicode symbol instead of a newline?

Comment: @AndrasDeak No, because it really depends on the program how it shows non-printable characters like a newline character.

Comment: Adding the .strip() fixed it. Thank you so much for the help! I read up on what you said as well